# Как следить за массивом объектов vue2

Tags: vue.js, websocket, ref, watch

В общем. в data() есть элемент model: [] и в него через this.$set добавляются ref() элементы

После того как я делаю что-то на другой странице значение в этих ref элементах меняется за счёт сокетов и соответственно в массиве оно тоже изменяется, но моя ф-ция watch никак не реагирует на это. Может знает кто в чём может быть дело?
Версия vue 2.7.14

```
model: {
            // eslint-disable-next-line vue/valid-model-definition
            handler(val, oldVal) {
                console.log(val, oldVal);
            },
            // eslint-disable-next-line vue/valid-model-definition
            deep: true,
            // eslint-disable-next-line vue/valid-model-definition
            // immediate: true,
        },
```

Comment: По-моему, в vue2 $refs не являются реактивными элементами.